# UISlider value, converted to NSNumber, = -1.10311e-146

Tags: ios, floating-point, uislider, nsnumber

AI have a slider, I'm saving it's value to user defaults, and then grabbing that number in a different view.  I'm then converting that float to an NSNumber for use in a  CiRadialGradient filter.

I'm saving the value like:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:_alphaSlider.value forKey:@"Alpha"];
```

And retrieving like:

```
NSNumber *inRadius1 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"Alpha"]];
```

The problem is when grabbing the slider value and converting it to an NSNumber, I get the value of -1.10311e-146.  I'd expect something different.

In my storyboard the slider value is set from 0 to 100.  No matter where I place the slider, the value is always a large negative.

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: Paste in the rest of the code, where you save the value

Comment: It's in.  Logging the slider value shows it's at 100, and logging the retrieved value shows that's saving fine.  So it's the conversion I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess you're logging it like this:

```
NSLog(@"%f", inRadius1);
```

But actually an NSNumber is an Objective-C object, so you should use `%@`:

```
NSLog(@"%@", inRadius1);
```

Comment: I'm logging the slider value with %f but am logging the NSNumber with %@.  Logging it with %g gives me 0.

Comment: Ahh, figured it out.  I was saving the slider.value and not an NSNumber version of that value.  Converting the value to an NSNumber, saving and working with that fixed the problem.  Thanks for making me re-look.  Will mark this as answered and write up my changes in 8 hours, not allowed to do it before :)